# List of synchronous dbcontext queries rewritten as async calls on separate contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

This post is in the context of using Entity Framework version 6.2.

Ok, so I have a rather slow endpoint that is essentially the following:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetCounts()
    {
        int count1 = service.GetCount1();
        int count2 = service.GetCount2();

        Models.Counts ret = new Counts()
        {
            Count1 = count1,
            Count2 = count2,
        };

        return Ok(ret);
    }
```

each call to the service is executed on the same instance of dbcontext:

```
//In the service
public class Service 
{
    private MyDbContext context;
    public Service() 
    { 
       context = new MyDbContext(); 
    } 

    public int GetCount1()
    { 
       return context.coll1.Count(); 
    }
    public int GetCount2()
    { 
       return context.coll2.Count(); 
    }
}
```

would it be better to treat each service call as separate units of work and create contexts for each one and then take advantage of EF's async methods like in the following:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCountsAsync()
    {
        var tcount1 = service.GetCount1Async();
        var tcount2 = service.GetCount2Async();

        await Task.WhenAll(tcount1, tcount2);

        int count1 = tcount1.Result;
        int count2 = tcount2.Result;

        Models.Counts ret = new Counts()
        {
            Count1 = count1,
            Count2 = count2
        };

        return Ok(ret);
    }
```

with changes in the service being

```
//In the service
public class Service 
{
    public Service() 
    { 
    } 

    public async Task<int> GetCount1()
    {
       using(var context = new MyDbContext()) 
       { 
           return await context.coll1.CountAsync();
       }
    }
    public async Task<int> GetCount2()
    {
       using(var context = new MyDbContext())
       { 
           return await context.coll2.CountAsync();
       } 
    }
}
```

Are there downsides to this? It works and has definitely improved performance of the query.

I am rather new to threading (in this case async / wait) so am unfamiliar with potential downsides or if what I have above is an antipattern, but part of me feels like there can be issues with this structure while using EF's dbcontext ?? Hopefully that is just my ignorance creating that feeling.

Also to note, I had the service rewrite initially with the context as a field of the service class; however, ended up getting the error:

*A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.*

Changing the life cycle of the context to the method calls fixed this, but seeing that error in general made me nervous of this general strategy.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are doing this the right way,

1. You shouldn't cache a `DbContext`, the sql connections are cached for you already under the hood. Doing so can cause all sorts of subtle errors, which you have already encountered.
2. The contexts aren't thread safe.
3. They are fairly light-weight so performance shouldn't really be a concern.
4. And are best placed in a using statement with small packets of work

All-in-all, putting each `GetCount` seems like the best approach